# Google maps one placemark instead of many when zooming out

Tags: google-maps

I have a google map with several placemarks, when you zoom out on it at some point several placemarks that are close, show as one, in the domain of the app this is a serious problem.

Is there anyway to show some sort of count or make obvious the fact that there are more than one placemark?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MarkerClusterer](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/) was recently released on the [GMaps Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/).  It's the fastest client-side clusterer I've seen so far.  There's a great example [here](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html) which shows some of the options you can tweak.

[This page](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/) compares and benchmarks some of the options available to you, and concludes that MarkerClusterer is the fastest.

Just keep in mind that if you have several thousand markers, any client-side solutions will probably be too slow.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extension by Martin Pearman that addresses this situation:

[ClusterMarker](http://googlemapsapi.110mb.com/clustermarker/) detects any groups of two or more markers whose icons visually intersect when displayed. Each group of intersecting markers is then replaced with a single cluster marker. The cluster marker, when clicked, simply centres and zooms the map in on the markers whose icons previously intersected.

There seems to be a problem with the redirection on Martin's page at the moment, but if you keep reloading it eventually works.